# Djoser verify or activate email address when reset or changed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, djoser

I was unable to Verfiy a user when user changed their `email` address

`serializers.py`

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer as BaseUserSerializer


class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'password']


class UserSerializer(BaseUserSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'email']


class UserDeleteSerializer(Base...):
    pass
```

`settings.py`

```
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        ...
    },
    'PERMISSIONS': {
        ...
    }
}
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        ...
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        ...

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        ...
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        ...
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    soft_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None

    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["name"]

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = "%s" % (self.name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to add some functionality when user `POST` requested to
`base_url/auth/users/reset_email/` with `email=registed_email@gmail.com`

we received a `email` with a link having `uid` and `token` in a `link`

once user `POST` requested to `http://base_url/auth/users/reset_email_confirm/` with
`uid`, `token`, and `new_email` address I want to send an email address with `activation url` to newly `email` address and
`is_active` field should be `False` which will be active only with `activation url`